# OpenVZ Ubuntu 12.04 Mutt accent problem

Tags: 12.04, mutt, openvz

I'm trying to resolve the problem of accent on mutt because, they are displayed like '?' or '\123'.

I know there is a good documentation on mutt (http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttFaq/Charset) for this but i've tried all tips with no success.

I'm on a OpenVZ machine (Ubuntu 12.04 x86), this is my configuration for locales and charset on mutt :

.muttrc :

```
set charset=utf8
```

locale :

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
```

I don't find where is my error and how can i resolve this

Mutt version : Mutt 1.5.21 (2010-09-15)

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a investigation, i have found my problem..

I use putty to connect on my vm. I noticed that accent wasn't correct on the terminal.
So i configure putty to use UTF8 (default was ISO-8859-1) in **Window -> Translation -> Remote character set -> UTF8**

I also added this in **/etc/environment**

```
LANGUAGE=en

LC_ALL=en_US.utf8

LANG=en_US.utf8
```

So accent are correctly displayed on the terminal :

```
[root@Lu1204x86:~]$  echo é

é
```

Then i opened mutt but i noticed that subjects with accent are displayed with the problem of accent.

But when i opened a mail, all accents were correctly displayed ! Problem fixed !